# Is Raspbian Xorg server built in static form?

Tags: raspbian, xorg

I have noticed that in Raspbian no default `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is distributed and even if I create a file and modify it's contents it does not seem to take effect sometimes.
This is where I studied the man pages of xorg.conf and found the following sentence:

> [The Module] section is ignored when the Xorg server is built in
>   static form.

Therefore, I was wondering, has the Xorg server, which is distributed with Raspbian been built in "static form"? And, if yes, how can I get a "dynamic form"?

Thanks!

Comment: "it does not seem to take effect sometimes".  So sometimes it does take effect?  Does not that suggest that the Xorg server can not be static?

Comment: Well, good point. For me as a layman, it's not easy to find effects, so I didn't want to appear too confident on my theory. On the other hand I've mostly played around with the module section, which could possibly be ignored, while I left alone the other sections, where I had no business to do.